# Overwriting python log config

Tags: python, logging, module

I want to use an external module but this module configures the logger and I don't know how to overwrite it in order to log to file

```
#my main.py
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/thermostat/server.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)    

termo = SHT1x(dataPin, clkPin, SHT1x.GPIO_BOARD) #this one configures the log also

def main():
    logger.info("SERVER START")
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the module i am using is doing:

```
#SHT1x module
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(____name____)

def main():
    #....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So my program is logging to console not to server.log
Is there a way to overwrite this behavior?

Comment: Modules should not be calling `logging.basicConfig`. Only the main program should call `basicConfig` once, if at all. (`basicConfig` does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured. Can you change the module?

Comment: That was what i was reading also: libraries should not configure the logging, so yes I was thinking as a last resort to change the lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modules should not be calling `logging.basicConfig`. Only the main program
should call `basicConfig` once, if at all. [Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), `basicConfig` does
nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured.

If you can not modify the SHT1x module, then as a workaround, you could arrange
for `main.py` to call its `logging.basicConfig` *before* importing SHT1x. The
`basicConfig` call that executes first will be the only one that affects logging.

```
def main():
    import SHT1x
    logger.info("SERVER START")
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    termo = SHT1x.somefunction(dataPin, clkPin, SHT1x.GPIO_BOARD) #this one configures the log also


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/thermostat/server.log',
                        level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)    
    
    main()
```

Note: I've modified my first suggestion so `main.py` calls `logging.basicConfig`
inside the `if __name__== "__main__"` suite. This preserves your ability to use `main.py` as both a script and a module.

Comment: I think i tried configuring the logger from main first but that did not work since I did not change the import also (did not know you can import like that)